# How to insert, update, and delete data from a database table using DataGridView?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, adodb

I am using `DataGridView` in VB Dot Net to show data from Database table in it. I am able to show it. Now I want to be able to update, delete, insert records in my database table when I make any changes in my `DataGridView` grid on the click of a button.

How do I achieve this?

<sub>(I am using ADODB as my connection object to connect to the database.)</sub>

Comment: How are you populating your dgv?

Comment: @bamie9l.. I am binding the DGV to the DataSource during design time by adding Database Table to it..

Comment: This might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/779f97cf-0f09-4c5a-9cde-097a717179db/how-to-save-datagridview-changes-into-database

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at command fields. They offer a way to add Select, Edit, Delete to gridviews. 
Here is a link to documentation with a nice example at the bottom.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield(v=vs.110).aspx